# Amplify pull not fetching Amplify studio components

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I was looking into the figma and Amplify sync capability recently released by AWS. Looks promising. However, I can't seem to pull the components to my local repository after I have synced with figma.

I created some components in figma that are successfully synced into amplify studio. Under UI-Library > My Components, all my components are there, as expected.

The problem is I am not getting anything to my local computer after running `amplify pull`. The only thing I get is a `cli.json` and `team-provider-info.json` file. From the documentation it says I should simply import my components from `ui-components` like:

```
import {Button} from './ui-components';
```

But in order to do that I was expecting a folder to be pulled from amplify called `ui-components`. Like shown in this [video](https://youtu.be/7MKVCmNKT1c?t=241), its clear that ui-components is a folder that gets added under src. But why is `amplify pull` not fetching it? According to [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/uibuilder/override/) it should.

Answer (score 7):

It seems as if the problem is that my project is a react-native project. As of writing this it seems there is only support for react. I have tried googling but have been unable to find if support for react-native is coming. I would hope so!

Comment: `amplify configure project` can be used to change a project from `react-native` to `react`

Comment: [Here's the current status of Amplify UI for React Native](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react-native/getting-started/introduction#current-status). Right now only the "cloud connected" components are available in RN - that includes Authenticator and Messaging. Primitives and Figma support is "coming soon". There is also a [component matrix in Github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/#component-matrix).