# Amplify CLI not syncing UI Components on pull

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have run through AWS Amplify's full-stack application tutorials multiple times to create a react native app, every time with the same result.  The UI components created in AWS Amplify Studio are not being synced to my local codebase on pull.

The steps I followed on my most recent attempt:

1. Create Amplify app via AWS Amplify console
2. Configure UI Components/sync with Figma
3. Using the "Local Setup Instructions" link at the top right of Amplify studio, performed an amplify pull

The amplify pull always succeeds but never pulls UI components. If I set up a backend data or auth, I will see those synced properly, but I never see this (screenshot from a youtube vid):
[image]

And no ui-components folder is created in my source code.  I'm at a loss, I've watched videos and followed tutorials from different people and nothing seems to work.  The results are always the same and the rest of the functionality works as expected (graphql schema, auth, etc).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319348/amplify-pull-not-fetching-amplify-studio-components), which is similar, but outdated as from what I can tell Amplify should now support react native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was that I started developing my app using Vue. When I later on switched to React, the config file still thought it was Vue that I was using.

I had to switch from Vue to "react" in the .config/project-config.json.

```
{
    ...
    "javascript": {
        "framework": "react", // This line
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, except my config had "framework": none. Changed it to react like @Jimmie mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75554174/5834519 and it worked